# Why is my initialized object not being passed to my spark tasks

Tags: scala, apache-spark

```
object MyObj extends Serializable{
    private var a: String = _
    private var b: String = _
    //other vars handled in init
    ...
    def init(x: String, y: String): Unit = {
        this.a = x
    }
    def exec(z: String): String = {
        //want to return value x from init
        this.a
    }
}
```

Then my spark portion -

```
MyObj.init("one", "two")
myData.map({s => 
                 MyObj.exec(s.toString) 
             }).saveAsTextFile(outFile)
```

However, all of the properties initilized with `init` are null when running `exec` within spark.  How do I fix this?

Update - follow up :

```
//works
myData.map({s => 
                 MyObj.init("one", "two")
                 MyObj.exec(s.toString) 
             }).saveAsTextFile(outFile)


//can't serialize error
val one= "one"
myData.map({s => 
                 MyObj.init(one, "two")
                 MyObj.exec(s.toString) 
             }).saveAsTextFile(outFile)
```

Updated 2 with broadcast test(fails) -

```
MyObj.init("one", "two")
val myObj = sc.broadcast(MyObj)     
distData.map({s => 
                  myObj.value.exec(s.toString) 
             }).saveAsTextFile(outFile)
```

Comment: What happens if you broadcast the singleton? `val myObj = sc.broadcast(MyObj)` after initializing it; and then within the `map`: `myObj.value.exec(s.toString)`.

Comment: Same result, initilizations are null, updated main post if you want to see what I tried.

Comment: Could you provided the implementation of `init` and `exec` in order to exactly reproduce?

Comment: Update `MyObj` in main post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You initialized you object in Driver JVM but not in executors where parallel code is  executed.

```
MyObj.init("one", "two")  // Run in driver
myData.map({s => MyObj.exec(s.toString)})  // Run in executors
.saveAsTextFile(outFile)
```

This should work:

```
myData.map({s => 
     MyObj.init("one", "two")
     MyObj.exec(s.toString)
})
.saveAsTextFile(outFile)
```

Depend on your use case a common pattern is use Object as Java Singleton Pattern

```
object MyObject {
   lazy val (a,b) = init

   private def init() = {
      // Initialize a,b. Maybe connection to rest endpoints, 
      // databases or just use environment variables to set up
   }

   def exec(param1, ..) = {
     // your stuff
   }

}
```

Comment: Thanks, one follow up, how do I pass variables into `MyObj.init`? It will only allow hardcoded strings, I get serialization error otherwise(I edited my main question for further explanation)

Comment: You might want to use `mapPartition` with this solution in order to initialize the object only once per partition.

Comment: @jayjay93 if you use a variable from outside the map or mapPartitions (good suggestion), spark will try to serialize the entire class. Probably you have other non-serializable objects. Try broadcast variable 'one' instead MyObj